# Concerned with Tails vulnerabilities

Tags: privacy

Regarding this: http://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2014/07/21/exploit-dealer-snowdens-favourite-os-tails-has-zero-day-vulnerabilities-lurking-inside/

Apparently, even the version of Tails released yesterday contains critical 0day vulnerabilities potentially compromising anyone's anonymity, which are sold by Exodus Intelligence.

I am no security expert, only just now starting to take my online privacy seriously, so my main question is: Is using Tails any less secure than carefully building my own privacy-focused stack to boot from USB or use in a VirtualBox, or is a combo of software I choose myself just as likely to contain such vulnerabilities?

Furthermore - is my stack any more secure if I throw in a VPN?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a word on security: Security does not exist in a vacuum; it is completely dependent on the circumstance.

Defending against an unrealized threat is wasteful. Not defending against a trivial attack renders your system useless. As such, blindly adding security measures is an exercise in futility. One must have a well-defined set of goals for a system, also known as a **threat model**.

If you intend on achieving "online privacy," you should define your own threat model. Some questions to ask yourself:

- Who is your adversary? (Are you defending against script kiddies? The NSA?)
- What behavior do you intend on keeping confidential?

What about the system you would use to address this model?

- What compromises are you willing to make to keep your behavior confidential?
- What are the constraints on your solution? (e.g. time, budget, hardware, etc.)

---

Now that you have defined the boundaries of your problem and those of your solution, you need to determine what portion of this you can fulfill and at what cost. Here is where your question comes in:

> Is using Tails any less secure than carefully building my own privacy-focused stack...?

This is ultimately about the tradeoff between threat coverage and cost (your development time). Essentially: What security do you gain from cobbling together a secure live OS that you wouldn't have with a product like Tails (and vice versa)? Your proposition is that a system you design will either 1. Have fewer bugs/exploits and/or 2. Have fewer *known* bugs/exploits.

First, it is entirely possible (albeit unlikely) that, at any one point in time, a system you have built with publicly available "blocks" will have fewer bugs than an open-source system already in use. The benefit of FOSS is that many eyes on the code means a higher likelihood that a bug will get discovered AND will get patched. Code that you write will inevitably have bugs which you will be much less likely to catch unless you spend your days reviewing source (even then there may be some issues even you cannot spot).

Addressing the issue of known bugs, "rolling your own" system is essentially security through obscurity (or, perhaps more accurately, [security through minority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity#Security_through_minority)), that is, relying on an attacker's unfamiliarity with a system to ensure its security. In general, this does not represent a marked increase in security, certainly not if you use FOSS building blocks.

The Tails project itself is actually quite similar to the "combo of software" you describe. Quoting directly from [Tails' Contribute page](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/how/code/#index1h2):

> ...We try not to reinvent the wheel, and we flee the *Not invented here* syndrome like the plague. Very little code is actually written specifically for Tails...We glue existing pieces together.

This underscores the inherent tradeoff in developing a security system: Each line of code and each new design decision increases the likelihood of a bug being introduced.

---

While it may be tempting to read about these 0day revelations and say "I could do this better," it is important to realize the benefits that accompany widely available, open-source tools. If you aren't willing to put in the time and effort required to develop and maintain an entire secure OS (a daunting task for a large team let alone a single developer), then you might consider adding another set of eyes (read: yours) to an existing project. But that's just my 2¢.

Comment: Thanks, this pretty much covers everything I wanted to be sure about :)

Answer (score 2):

Almost all software of significant complexity, especially software dealing with network communications, contain vulnerabilities.  A subset of those vulnerabilities are known to some bad actors who will use them in various ways (0-days).  Whether you build the distribution yourself or use an off-the-shelf distro, some of these vulnerabilities may exist in your software.

I've never looked at the TAILS stack specifically, so I couldn't say much about their practices, but I imagine they've put a lot of thought and effort into mitigating what unknown vulnerabilities may exist by minimizing attack surface and careful configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Something you build yourself may be more secure or it may not be.  You don't know how secure a system is until it is tested and looked at by lots of people.  This is why the saying "don't roll your own" is very common in security.

Your own system would have the advantage of not being vulnerable to out of as many out of the box attacks as a larger system, so unless you are specifically targeted, you may be safer, but chances are extremely good that your custom solution will have far more actual holes in it than a popular system.  Those holes may be less well known, but if you are specifically being attacked, it will likely make you easier to compromise.

Use of a VPN also depends on the type of attacker you expect.  If you are worried about a non-governmental organization trying to compromise you, a VPN helps you become anonymous, but if you are dealing with the resources of a government, a VPN rapidly becomes a much weaker defense if not potentially making you easier to identify.